# Employee Hierarchy at different levels

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema, rdbms

I have 5 tables in my database called Employee, Company, Team, Locations and Position. Now Positions are assigned to employee on each of these levels i.e. to Company, Team and Location. To resolve this I have created 3 tables called CompanyPosition, TeamPosition and LocationPosition. An employee can hold multiple positions in each of these level i.e I can be a CEO, MD at company level etc.

Now I have a situation that in each of these position tables an employee can hold multiple positions and he will reports to someone holding multiple positions, but to only one of position at a time.

I am thinking of creating a new column called ReportstoPositionId in each of these tables CompanyPosition, TeamPosition and LocationPosition to solve this problem.

Can anyone suggest me that I am going in right direction or it can have some problem now or in furture.

[image]

Comment: While this is a great problem to solve, it's not really suitable for the Q&A format of StackOverflow due to the broad nature of any expected answers.

Comment: @ChupChapCharli, I would recommend you migrate your question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ . but please avoid having the same question posted on multiple sites at once.

Comment: @ChrisPickford: Thanks for replying back but I only need some hint or best practice for it, not complete solution :-)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for replying back but I have no idea about dba.stackexchange.com. Can you please suggest me how to migrate it to there.

Comment: There are two ways: delete this question here and post a new question directly on dba.stackexchange.com or request moderators to move the question. I have flagged your question as "should be migrated" but I can give no timeline as to if and when moderators will look into it.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for caring and sharing :-)

Comment: @ChupChapCharli, no idea why it was put on hold instead of just being migrated, these types of questions are common on dba site. Now I feel bad for drawing mod attention to your question.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115289/discussion-between-chupchapcharli-and-alex).